# How to use swift class in objective c (not an instance of the class)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

All tutorials for using swift code in a primarily objective-c app goes through this process mentioned in this Apple document https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

But this methodology of importing a `xyzProjectName-swift.h` file and then using

```
MySwiftClass *swiftObject = [[MySwiftClass alloc] init];
[swiftObject swiftMethod];
```

required me to create an instance of that swift class. Is it possible to directly access the class itself like `[MySwiftClass swiftMethod];`

I have not been able to do this until now. Do I have to change my swift code in a certain way to achieve this?

Comment: 1. You use the Swift class "directly" (aka sending a message to the class object itself) in the expression `[MySwiftClass alloc]`. Don't you? 2. What have you tried? Which problems did you get?

Comment: Well this function in swift class of mine just returns a specific uicolor according to the string i send it (its used across the app in many subclasses). So i dont want to alloc init at every place or declare it as a global ivar in all of my classes. Just want to use it as a regular class method. Till now i have been unable to directly access it. It tells me "No known class method for selector 'nameOfTheMethodIAmTryingToAccess'

Comment: @IshaanSejwal In addition to the simple function in my answer, I also tried your scenario with the Swift method `static func makeColor(str: String) -> UIColor` – works fine from Objective-C with `[MySwiftClass makeColor:@"blue"];`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just tried the following:

```
class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
    static func swiftMethod() -> String {
        return "hello"
    }
}
```

And in Objective-C:

```
NSLog(@"Received from Swift: %@", [MySwiftClass swiftMethod]);
```

Works for me - are you sure your `swiftMethod` is `static`, and not `private`? You could also try adding `@objc` in front of the `static func` – if nothing else, at least it might warn you if there is a reason it can't be accessed from Objective-C.

Comment: Ok putting static infront of my `func`s `let`s and `var`s worked (error disappeared. did not even use `@objc`). But I don't know why? can you tell me what was happening before and how it changed when I used `static`? From what i know `static` is used to retain an object for the lifetime of the app/process or to limit it from not being used by subclasses. How does `static` apply in this case?

Comment: @IshaanSejwal `@objc` is implicit when your class inherits from an Objective-C class, but you can use it for protocols and global functions to make them available from Obj-C. `static` means that the method or property is specific to the class itself, rather than an instance of the class (same is used in many other languages, e.g., Java). Without `static` the `MySwiftClass.swiftMethod()` would not even work in Swift…